# Как организовать сайт для подключения AdSense? (пишет "недостаточно контента")

Tags: html, sql, архитектура

Делаю сайт. Вот вредварительная версия: http://yttext.com/ . Пытался подключить AdSence. Получил отказ с мотивировкой:

> "Недостаточно контента. Для принятия Вашего сайта в программу AdSense и показа релевантных объявлений его страницы должны содержать достаточно текста, чтобы наши специалисты могли их проверить, а поисковый робот – определить их тематику."

Естественно так и будет, ведь у меня контент подгружается весь из БД динамически и конечно поисковый робот его не видит. Я вообще не программист - для меня это хобби. Так вот вопрос. Как правильно организовать сайт чтобы робот его мог парсить. И вообще прошу совета где хранить контент? Может мне все тексты скинуть в отдельные html файлы чтобы робот их проиндексировал?

Comment: `контент подгружается весь из БД динамически и конечно поисковый робот его не видит` - по идее, видит. Возмодно я ошибаюсь, но у гугла продвинутый робот, он сайты "видит" практически так же, как и мы. Опять таки, если я ни чего не путаю.

Comment: Скорее всего, вам не дают пройти AdSense т.к. на самом сайте пустовато, это действительно так... Попробуйте накидать больше информации.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что робот умеет вводить запросы в поиск. А структурировать не структурируемое для навигации я не знаю как.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps

Comment: это называется говносайт у вебмастеров, недостаточно текстового контента очевидно же, одностраничники не проходят модерацию в адсенсе.